# Power spectral density on the output of frequency modulator?

Tags: frequency, noise-spectral-density

Is there a formula with which we would be able to calculate the power spectral density on the output of a frequency modulator?

The information we know is that we have a receiver working in 180MHz that receives signals with bandwidth of 200kHz and the receiver is comprised of an antenna, the frequency modulator with amortization of 0.1dB and an amplifier with bandwidth of 9.9MHz and 10.1MHz, gain of 4.5dB and noise figure 2.5dB .

We also know that the temperature is 27 degrees Celcius. The noise temperature of the antenna is 100 degrees Kelvin and the SNR fraction at the input is 12.5dB

What would a voltometer show for the voltage on the output?

Comment: a multimeter wouldn't measure anything sensible – its bandwidth is nowhere close to 200 kHz, let alone 180 MHz.

Comment: A frequency modulator is presumably a device for creating an FM signal and would not be used in a receiver.  The receiver has some version of a frequency demodulator (sometimes referred to as a discriminator) whose function is to recover the modulating signal from the receiver FM input. What do you mean by amortization? The output of your receiver should be that signal.  Its actual voltage depends on the configuration of your receiver of which you have given us no details.

Comment: @Barry I added some more information, maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: There ain't no "voltometers."  As for a **voltmeter** is would show **nada, nothing, nienta, zip, zero.**  The output you want to measure is **far** outside of what **any** voltmeter can do.  There are RF power meters that could be of use, and RF spectrum analyzers that would be of more use.

Comment: @JRE thank you , what about the power spectral density?

Comment: That's what RF spectrum analysers are for.